# Density estimation in machine learning generative models

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, machine-learning

I don't understand why thanks to the reconstruction of a given probability distribution -given a number of observations- it is possible to create new observations.

I know that obtaining an unknown pdf, can give us information on other samples than the observed( with the related frequencies) and in this sense, we are able to have a new observation but in what direction we can apply this approach on data sets like the MNIST or faces that are used in generative models in ML? I suppose that we have to consider P(X) in which X is a vector in multidimensional space. Am I right? Are there books or reosurces to fix this concept?

Many thanks

Comment: This question is not very clear. The easiest example of what could be your intended meaning of "creating new observations" would be sampling the reconstructed probability distribution, which one can always do. What this really means in ML depends on your specific setting.

Comment: In some sense my question regards how to estimate probability density functions of images and how to sample the reconstructed PDF.  In this case, the X in P(X) are vectors of n pixels that compose the images or it is the image itself that is the X?